# How to connect cassandra which is in a docker image from outside the OS

Tags: ubuntu, docker, cassandra

configured docker in a ubuntu OS. installed cassandra node in docker. cassandra node shows ip as 17.7.0.1 and and ubuntu IP as 10.7.108.10. how can i connect connect cassandra from other machine in the same network . I have tried docker run -p 10.7.108.10 9043:9043 cassandra:latest. still lsof -i :9043 not giving any result , neither i'm able to connect from other machines. telnet also not working.

Comment: did you expose the port of casandra in the docker file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are exposing the port and want to access it via the host IP of the system running docker, you should configure the `broadcast_rpc_address` in cassandra.yaml to be that of your ubuntu server (`10.7.108.10`).

If you are using the official cassandra image you can pass in `-e CASSANDRA_BROADCAST_ADDRESS=10.7.108.10` [as documented](https://hub.docker.com/_/cassandra/).

Additionally, I see that you are exposing port 9043.  Are you explicitly configuring the binary port in that way?  It defaults to 9042.

Comment: thank you , this document was helpful. And i was using 9042 , that was a typo. Thanks once again for your help.